# Can I decrypt a DiskCryptor-encrypted hard drive using Veracrypt?

Tags: encryption, linux, truecrypt, veracrypt

I have a hardrive I encrypted with DiskCryptor back when I was using Windows. Now that I have Linux I want to decrypt the hard drive but it turned out DiskCryptor is not available for Linux, whereas Veracrypt is. So I have two ideas:

1) Try to decrypt the hard drive on my Linux machine using Veracrypt.

2) Alternatively, use Wine to run DiskCryptor and use it to decrypt the hard drive.

If neither of the options are possible, I will use another Windows machine but I don't have one myself so that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Why isn't DiskCryptor available on Linux? Also, this might be better off on SuperUser.

Comment: I don't know, ask the developers.

Comment: Wow, I was under the assumption it was available for Linux, but apparently it's not: `Other operation systems (like Linux, etc.) are currently not supported and no plans exist to add support.`. You learn something new every day.

Comment: Yeha, I was also under this assumption, I would never thought this may be an issue - but it is. So do you have any idea on how to decrypt this drive without a second Windows machine?

Comment: I'd go with the second windows machine to avoid any unforeseen issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about finding software to support a particular format, with no security implication whatsoever. It would be on-topic on [unix.se] or [su].

Answer (score 1):

VeraCrypt documentation web pages (https://veracrypt.codeplex.com/documentation) do not say DiskCryptor and VeraCrypt are compatible!  And the web pages do not say we can convert a DiskCryptor volume to a VeraCrypt volume.  A TrueCrypt volume is ok, though.

If VercaCrypt cannot mount the hard drive, it cannot decrypt it.  I doubt VeraCrypt program will mess up with the hard drive.  But I will not risk to try to do that if the hard drive does not have any backup and the data in the hard drive are really important.

Answer (score 1):

The docs for diskcryptor state:

> DiskCryptor releases from 0.1 to 0.4 were fully compatible with TrueCrypt, as they used a corresponding partition format and encrypted data with AES-256 algorithm in LRW mode. Starting from DiskCryptor 0.5, the program relies upon its own partition format, developed specifically for encrypting partitions with data on them, as TrueCrypt format has been originally meant for creation of empty volumes. That move allowed for an increase in DiskCryptor's stability, eliminated many problems associated with file systems, and created an optimal format for further development of the program.

Given veracrypt's truecrypt origins, I think it's safe to assume that the two are incompatible, unless you made your diskcryptor volume many versions ago.

Answer (score 0):

One could run a Virtual Box machine with windows OS and then mount the Diskcryptor encrypted drive that way and allow the flow of files from VM to Host for transferring.

I have not done this yet, but in theory, it is a viable option for Linux transition from previous Windows environments, which also requires minimal resources to accomplish. No need for another PC and USB devices are supported as well.

Alternatively, if you are thinking about moving into Linux from Windows, just decrypt the drive prior that holds all your data.